# Normalizing a list of names in Python

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list of names :

```
names = ['King ARTHUR',
         'Lancelot The brave',
         'galahad the  pure',
         'Servant  patsy',
         'GALAHAD THE PURE']
```

How could I normalize the list so that "the" are always in lowercase and only the first letters of the names are captilized and delete the extra spaces and the duplicated names of  the list

ex:.Galahad the Pure

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This site is intended to be a database of questions and answers for programmers who may be stuck on a particular technical problem. Your question appears to be more of a "I need to write some code to perform this task, but I don't know where to start". It's very specific, and unlikely to help others in the future. This, unfortunately, is not a good fit for SO. Please may I suggest that you take a look at [ask]. If you have already made an attempt at coding this yourself, then please show your efforts and tell us how it didn't work

Comment: Maybe start by looking at the [String Methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods), e.g. `capitalize()` does sound like something you want to do. Try something for yourself and come back here, when you have specific questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string methods. If you encounter a 'the' in any form, you just put it into lower case. Every other part of the string is assumed to be a name and is capitalized.

```
names = list(set([' '.join(i.lower() if i.lower() == 'the' else i.capitalize() for i in name.split())
                  for name in names]))
```

This uses the **join**() method to merge the modified parts of the string again and builds a new list based on the names list.
To eliminate duplicates, the set function is used, finally the set is converted back to a list.